# sybase iq - "operation failed on file due to file permission"

Tags: file, sybase, bigdata

I'm trying to get to a local file from sybase iq.

My code to connect to my file is like this:

```
USNIG CLIENT FILE 'C://TEMP/A.TXT'
```

If i run it on iq workspace it's working perfectly.

If i run this query via a service.cs it's not working and i get error:

ERROR [HY000] "operation failed on file due to file permission FILE: C://TEMP/A.TXT

i tried to find an answer via google but nothing...

the DSN is ok.

Any idea what to do?
Thanks!

Comment: obvious question: does your application (or, more precisely, the account that the application is running under) have permission to open the file? When you get a permission error, clearly this is the first thing to check.

Comment: @ADyson hey, thanks for your time. the service.cs (c# file) and the txt file in a same folder. and i gave permission to everyone to read and write on the txt file.